# Ignoring FileNotFoundExceptions in jsp's (Weblogic)

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, weblogic

I'm working on upgrading a legacy application from Weblogic 10 to version 12, and we're running into many cases where there are `<jsp:include />`'s on files that don't exist. Currently the application silently fails, and just doesn't include anything for those includes. In version 12, however, we get a `FileNotFoundException` from `NestedServletResponse.handleResourceNotFoundFromDefaultServlet`, causing the whole request to break.

Is it possible to configure Weblogic to have the old behavior? There are unfortunately too many files to go through to find all the broken includes.

Comment: Do you have further detail on those FileNotFound exceptions? They could be directly linked to those failing includes.

Comment: @AmirKeibi I have no doubt the FileNotFound exceptions are because of those failing includes. What I'd like is for the includes to fail silently without throwing exceptions.